# Logging instrument time with a simulator with only a CFI present

Tags: flight-training

I am a private pilot working on my instrument rating.  I have all my required instruction time and am working to build time to my 40 hours.  My new flight school has a qualified simulator. My CFII is on long term leave. Can I use the simulator with just a CFI and log simulated time?  The Federal Aviation Regulation, [14 CFR Part 61.65 (h)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61#p-61.65(h)), just says authorized instructor.

Comment: Thanks for the correction…yes, authorized. Its subsection h under 61.65

Answer (score 1):

[FAR 61.65(d)(2)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61#p-61.65(d)(2)) is a little more nuanced than a simple yes or no answer.

> Forty hours of actual or simulated instrument time in the areas of operation listed in paragraph (c) of this section, of which **15 hours must have been received from an authorized instructor who holds an instrument-airplane rating**, and the instrument time includes:

The way I read this is a CFI (no II) can provide instruction for 25 of the required 40 hours.  A CFII must provide at least 15 hours.

Do I think this is wise?  No!

An authorized instructor (CFI or CFII) is required for simulator time to count towards an instrument rating.

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61#p-61.65(h) is that this time must be logged under the administration of a authorized flight instructor who has an instrument rating on his/her flight instructor certificate.  So, no, you may not do this on your own  and log the time toward an instrument rating without the supervision of a CFII present and signed off as dual instruction time.  This isn’t to say that you cannot practice flying the simulator on instruments on your own, but you will not be able to log that time toward your rating.

Comment: Once the OP gets his or her instrument rating then they could log this approved simulator time towards IR currency without any instructor at all.

So OP should stay in good graces with the sim's owner.